# Longtable and regular cline on pagebreak not working?

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, cline

Besides having issues with forced nopagebreaks, a cline does not seem to work on a regular pagebreak. Only hline seems to work.
How can I get clines to work on Longtables?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{170mm}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline %same result

Mkay & Okay \\ \cline{1-2}
Mkay & Okay \\ \cline{1-2}
Mkay & Okay \\ \cline{1-2}
Mkay & here \\ \cline{1-2}%\hhline{--}
Hmm & Okay \\ \cline{1-2}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second example here should work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44800/2388. Use then `\ltcline{--}` instead of \cline.

Comment: Thank you so much, you do not even know how much I love you. If I can do anything in return, please let me know :)

Comment: You should better thank @DavidCarlisle ;-). He wrote the patch, I only found it.