# How to remove line in cell table?

Tags: tables

I have working code which produce the image below:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}

{\makegapedcells
  \begin{longtable}{|c|L{2.5cm}|L{5cm}|L{1.8cm}|L{2.1cm}|}
    \caption{My Table}\\
    \hline
    \thead{No} & \thead{A} & \thead{B} & \thead{C} &  \thead{D} \\\hline
    %
    1 & FOO-01 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & John & Lorem \\\hline
    1.1 & FOO-01-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. &  & \\\hline
    1.2 & FOO-01-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & & \\\hline
    2 & FOO-02 & Nam posuere turpis et & Doe & Ipsum\\\hline
    2.1 & FOO-02-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. & &\\\hline
    2.2 & FOO-02-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & &\\\hline
  \end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However I want to remove some line in the certain cell to become like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `\cline{fromcolumn-tocolumn}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}

{\makegapedcells
  \begin{longtable}{|c|L{2.5cm}|L{5cm}|L{1.8cm}|L{2.1cm}|}
    \caption{My Table}\\
    \hline
    \thead{No} & \thead{A} & \thead{B} & \thead{C} &  \thead{D} \\\hline
    %
    1 & FOO-01 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & John & Lorem \\\cline{1-3}
    1.1 & FOO-01-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. &  & \\\cline{1-3}
    1.2 & FOO-01-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & & \\\hline
    2 & FOO-02 & Nam posuere turpis et & Doe & Ipsum\\\cline{1-3}
    2.1 & FOO-02-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. & &\\\cline{1-3}
    2.2 & FOO-02-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & &\\\hline
  \end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:* in case of a table which goes on many pages, with `\pagebreak` you can force a page break to avoid the separation of a group of cells.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}

{\makegapedcells
  \begin{longtable}{|c|L{2.5cm}|L{5cm}|L{1.8cm}|L{2.1cm}|}
    \caption{My Table}\\
    \hline
    \thead{No} & \thead{A} & \thead{B} & \thead{C} &  \thead{D} \\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \thead{No} & \thead{A} & \thead{B} & \thead{C} &  \thead{D} \\\hline
    \endhead
    %
    1 & FOO-01 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & John & Lorem \\\cline{1-3}
    1.1 & FOO-01-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. &  & \\\cline{1-3}
    1.2 & FOO-01-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & & \\\hline
    2 & FOO-02 & Nam posuere turpis et & Doe & Ipsum\\\cline{1-3}
    2.1 & FOO-02-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. & &\\\cline{1-3}
    2.2 & FOO-02-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & &\\\hline
    1 & FOO-01 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & John & Lorem \\\cline{1-3}
    1.1 & FOO-01-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. &  & \\\cline{1-3}
    1.2 & FOO-01-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & & \\\hline
    2 & FOO-02 & Nam posuere turpis et & Doe & Ipsum\\\cline{1-3}
    2.1 & FOO-02-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. & &\\\cline{1-3}
    2.2 & FOO-02-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & &\\\hline
    1 & FOO-01 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & John & Lorem \\\cline{1-3}
    1.1 & FOO-01-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. &  & \\\cline{1-3}
    1.2 & FOO-01-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & & \\\hline
    2 & FOO-02 & Nam posuere turpis et & Doe & Ipsum\\\cline{1-3}
    2.1 & FOO-02-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. & &\\\cline{1-3}
    2.2 & FOO-02-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & &\\\hline
        \pagebreak
    1 & FOO-01 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & John & Lorem \\\cline{1-3}
    1.1 & FOO-01-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. &  & \\\cline{1-3}
    1.2 & FOO-01-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & & \\\hline
    2 & FOO-02 & Nam posuere turpis et & Doe & Ipsum\\\cline{1-3}
    2.1 & FOO-02-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. & &\\\cline{1-3}
    2.2 & FOO-02-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & &\\\hline
    1 & FOO-01 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & John & Lorem \\\cline{1-3}
    1.1 & FOO-01-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. &  & \\\cline{1-3}
    1.2 & FOO-01-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & & \\\hline
    2 & FOO-02 & Nam posuere turpis et & Doe & Ipsum\\\cline{1-3}
    2.1 & FOO-02-01 & consectetur adipiscing elit. & &\\\cline{1-3}
    2.2 & FOO-02-02 & curabitur ut quam eu. & &\\\hline
  \end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whoa, thank you. I am afraid of using multicolumn package. Turn out there is simpler solution. Never heard of `cline` thanks. However `cline` didn't work if the table spread out in more than one page. [ltcilne](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44773/move-cell-with-rowspan-on-next-page/44800#44800) didn't work with my code above. Need help.

Comment: Which `multicolumn` package?

Comment: @azzamsa See my edit.

Comment: @Bernard I think azzamsa intended `multirow`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/longtable-multirow-problem-with-cline-and-nopagebreak) also didn't work for me (hope there will be a fix for longtable). For now I will you your updated solution (to use header every new page) or to adjust any break with `\hline` usage instead of `cline` manually.  You saved my day, thank you so much, hope you have great days there.

Comment: @azzamsa You can also avoid having header on every page, if you like, just remove the code between `\endfirsthead` (excluded) and `\endhead` (included).

Comment: @CarLaTeX tried it, but didn't work, maybe `cline` override those values. I will stick with manual adjustment for now.

Comment: @azzamsa Try with `\hline\endhead` after `\endfirsthead`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX oh no!. Your idea work. Instead of using two complex solution above I presented (which didn't work for me, and I am afraid also it affect other part of my document) adding  `\hline\endhead\hline\endfoot` after `\endfirsthead` work great for me. Billion thanks for you CarLatex :). I don't know why I never think of this tricky approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93203/discussion-between-carlatex-and-azzamsa).